# Why do I get this NullExceptionError?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I keep getting a NullExceptionError but I don't know why. I know that such an error occurs when I refer to an object that hasn't been initialized yet. In this situation the error apparently occurs in the second last line of the second file(I commented that one) but I'm pretty sure I've initialized everything in that line.. so I don't know what I should do to fix the error.

By the way, the files compile just fine, the error only appears when I press the left-arrow button.

```
public class SnakeGame {
JFrame frame;
Draw draw;
Timer timer;
int direction;

public static void main(String[] arg) {
    new SnakeGame();
}

SnakeGame() {
    draw = new Draw();

    frame = new JFrame("Snake");
    frame.add(draw, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.addKeyListener(draw);
    frame.requestFocusInWindow();
}

}
```

-

```
public class Draw extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {
SnakeGame snakeGame;
public Draw(SnakeGame snakeGame) {
    this.snakeGame = snakeGame;
}

public Draw() {
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    setFocusable(true);
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
        System.out.println("left pressed");
        setDirection(1);
    } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        System.out.println("right pressed");
    } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        System.out.println("UP pressed");
    } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
        System.out.println("down pressed");
    }
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){
}

public int getDirection(){
   return snakeGame.direction;
}

public void setDirection(int dir){
    snakeGame.direction = dir;  //According to the compiler the error occurs here
    System.out.println(snakeGame.direction);
}

}
```

Comment: Where have you initialized `snakeGame`?

Comment: And it's not the compiler that gives you a `NullPointerException`, it's the runtime environment.

Comment: You should probably use `draw = new Draw(this)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I see it correctly, the only way to initialize `snakeGame` would be to call `Draw(SnakeGame snakeGame)`, which as far as I see it is never called.

In your `SnakeGame` constructor you're calling `new Draw();` which you might want to change to `new Draw(this);`. You'd then also want to make the calls in the no-argument constructor `Draw()` in the other as well, e.g. `setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));` etc.

As a side note: `Draw` looks a lot like a method  name (that's why I at first thought `Draw()` was a setter and not a constructor. You'd make your life easier if you changed the class name to something like `DrawPanel` etc., i.e. use nouns for class names, verbs or "commands" for method names etc.

See this wikipedia article for basic naming conventions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29

Using those makes your life as a programmer easier and increases your chances to get help from others since they're more likely to understand your code.

Comment: IMO, "DrawPanel" still sounds verb-y:  It sounds like a good name for a method that draws a panel.  I'd go for "GamePanel" or "GameBoard" or "SnakePit" or...

Comment: @jameslarge you're right it might be confusing, although the case might make a difference here: "DrawPanel" might mean a panel to draw onto while "drawPanel" means the act of drawing a panel. IMHO in terms of naming conventions "DrawPanel" would be ok (and I suggested for minimal adjustment needed) but your suggestions would be more appropriate. In fact "DrawPanel" might be a bit too general a name.

Answer (score 1):

You never initialized `snakeGame;` therefore `snakeGame == null`. You need to initialize it in your default constructor like `SnakeGame snakeGame = new SnakeGame()`

I'm also curious why `SnakeGame` and `Draw` both have each other as private members.